# Convert an ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<SomeClass> java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've managed to convert an arraylist of some class (in my case it's a class which extends `ArrayAdapter<Question>`) to an `ArrayList<String>`. I've passed it through an android intent bundle and received through the getStringArrayList method. Now I need to convert it back to the `ArrayList<Question>` to set my adapter up

**Converting from `ArrayList<Question>` to `ArrayList<String>`**

```
       questionlists = task.execute(myitem).get();

        for (Question object : questionlists) 
        {
            strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
        }
        simpleArray2 = new String[strings.size()];
        strings.toArray(simpleArray2);
```

**Converting back to `ArrayList<Question>`**

```
 List<Question> variable;
 lists = getArguments().getStringArrayList("Question");
     variable = (List<Question>)(List<?>) lists;

  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_world, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sessions);
    final QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getActivity(), variable);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
             //inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  
             //lists);  
   // lv.setAdapter(adapter);             
    return view;
}
```

I've added a try/catch my adapter and I get the error:

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.com.example.Question.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I haven't converted back to a proper ArrayList first?

Comment: `variable = (List<Question>)(List<?>) lists;` what the. That won't work.

Comment: That is where I try to convert an arraylist<String>, which I've passed through my putStringArrayList call, to an arrayList of Questions so that I may display it in my adapter

Comment: `List<Question>` is not the same as `List<String>` because `Question` is not the same as `String`. You should make the `Question` class `Parcelable` using http://www.parcelabler.com/ and send an array of Parcelable instead of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. To convert from `List<Question>` to `List<String>` you already do this:

**Converting from ArrayList to ArrayList**

```
   List<Question> questionlists = task.execute(myitem).get();
   List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Question object : questionlists) 
    {
        strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
    }
```

Now to convert from `List<String>` to `List<Question>` you'd have to do exactly the same, just the other way round:

```
   List<String> strings = ... result from above
   List<Question> questionlists = new ArrayList<Question>();

    for (String object : strings) 
    {
        questionlists.add(object != null ? object.toQuestion() : null);
    }
```

**Oh, wait!** `String` does not have a `toQuestion()` method! What now? Well, we just make such a method ourselves. As it's going to be a method that creates a `Question` object, why not make it a Constructor of Question, taking a String as parameter?

```
   List<String> strings = ... result from above
   List<Question> questionlists = new ArrayList<Question>();

   for (String object : strings) 
   {
       questionlists.add(object != null ? new Question(object) : null);
   }
```

Now all that's left to do, is to add that Constructor to your question class.

```
class Question {
    public Question(String string) {
        // implementing this the right way is up to you...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to help a lot and make so much sense!

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you're not actually casting a `Question` to a `String`.  You're calling the `toString()` method for a `Question`.

For example,

```
public class Question {

    //instance member
    String question;

    public String toString() {
       return question;
    }
}
```

In order to go from a `String` to a `Question`, you're going to have to write a constructor or method that takes a `String` as a parameter and returns a `Question`.

For example, you could add this constructor to your `Question` class:

```
public Question(string myQuestion) {
     question = myQuestion;
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest I do it? In my first example, strings is an Arraylist of strings.

Comment: @user1397978 Hopefully my update helps explain things.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` is a method that all Java `Object` objects have.  By default, it will list the name of the class and the memory location of the reference.  You're not actually converting the object `Question` to `String`.  You are generating a `String` that in some what interprets what `Question` is.  For example, you can overwrite `toString()` to generate whatever you want.

```
public class Question {

  String mQuestion;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return mQuestion;
  }
}
```

Now, what you can do is make some sort of custom String in `toString()` that fully represents your `Question` object.  Then have a `fromString` method that parses your custom String and builds new `Question` objects from it.  However, this method is error prone and limiting.

A better method would be to either inherit `Question` from `Serializable` or better yet [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).  Doing this allows you to put the actual `Question` object in to a Bundle and pull it out from the Intent without any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand Type Casting correctly.

Type casting is not conversion. It is asking java to assume for the rest of that context that the real type of that object is what you say it is. You are telling java that even though it is not obvious in the current context, you know better about what the actual type of the object is.

Information about the exact type of an object is not available in every context. As you pass objects around, methods treat them as any of their super class types right up to Object.

Type casting is a way to tell java that "I already know it is a List<Question> because I know who put that object there".

So, typecasting cannot help with conversion. The object should already be of that type for typecasting to work.

If it is of a different type, you have to write code to convert it.

```
public class ListProcessing {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

    //Take a list, convert and add to new list
    List<String> intStrs = listTransform(ints, new Converter<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String convert(Integer input) {
            return input==null?null:"S"+input.toString();
        }           
    });

    System.out.println(intStrs);
}

//Generic list processor
protected static <T,U> List<U> listTransform(List<T> in, Converter<T,U> converter){
    if(in==null) return null;
    List<U> out = new ArrayList<>();
    for(T item:in){
        out.add(converter.convert(item));
    }
    return out;
}

//An interface for a converter, which converts a single item
private static abstract class  Converter <T,U>{
    public abstract U convert(T input);
}
}
```